# How to set saved value for EnumDropDownListFor property in edit record

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, enums

I have created Enum for blood group.

I have a problem that how to set value which I am getting from data base for Blood Group field in controller. How to set value for **Enum_Member_BloodGroup = ?**  in contoller's Edit action.

I am getting data in **s.BloodGroup**

> Enum

```
public enum bloodGroup
{
        [Display(Name = "A +ve")]
        Apositive = 1,
        [Display(Name = "B +ve")]
        BPostive,
        [Display(Name = "AB +ve")]
        ABPositive,
        [Display(Name = "O +ve")]
        OPositive,
        [Display(Name = "A -ve")]
        ANegative,
        [Display(Name = "B -ve")]
        BNegative,
        [Display(Name = "AB -ve")]
        ABNegative,
        [Display(Name = "O -ve")]
        ONegative
}
```

> Model

```
public class EditStudentViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Blood Group")]
    public clsEnums.bloodGroup Enum_Member_BloodGroup { get; set; }
```

> Controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        try
        {

            using (TakshShilla_SchoolEntities objConnection = new TakshShilla_SchoolEntities())
            {
                var str = (from s in objConnection.tblStudents
                           where s.Student_ID == id
                           select new EditStudentViewModel
                           {
                               Student_ID = s.Student_ID,
                               FullName = s.FullName,
                               Standard = s.Standard,
                               RollNo = s.RollNo,                                  

                               Enum_Member_BloodGroup =
```

> View

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Enum_Member_BloodGroup, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="col-md-9">
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Enum_Member_BloodGroup, "--Select--")                               
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if it is coming in model property it should be set selected auto by helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cast the `int` value coming from database explicitly to your `Enum` type before assigining and in View it will get selected automatically by the html helper.

do this:

```
select new EditStudentViewModel
           {
              Student_ID = s.Student_ID,
              FullName = s.FullName,
              Standard = s.Standard,
              RollNo = s.RollNo,                                  
              Enum_Member_BloodGroup = (clsEnums.bloodGroup)s.BloodGroup
```